# Juju gui doesn't work

Tags: software-installation, juju

I have a problem with [juju](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/juju.1.html) gui.

I installed juju 2.7.5-bionic-amd64 with `snap install juju --classic` but when I tried to bootstrap the controller, this failure message appeared:

`Unable to fetch Juju GUI info: error fetching simplestreams metadata: "content-download" data not found`

i tried with `upgrade-gui`after bootstrap, and this failure message appeared :

`ERROR cannot upgrade to most recent release: cannot retrieve Juju GUI archive info: error fetching simplestreams metadata: "content-download" data not found`

Comment: You may wish to report this as a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bugs?field.searchtext=juju&search=Search+Bug+Reports&field.scope=project&field.scope.target=juju

Answer (score 2):

Same for me. I was forced to install `juju-gui` manually (xenial version):

```
juju deploy cs:juju-gui-142 --series xenial
juju expose juju-gui
```

Login info:

```
juju show-controller --show-password
```

Answer (score 0):

i face same problem and just found out !
It's because
 - Your juju controller (a host that running juju agent unable to connect to the internet)
I tried to fix it by adding 3rd net adapter that nat network
My juju controller is running as VM.